# Ghost Row in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

before i call Ghost Busters i came here to try the technoloy haha,

Well, i have a table in my Postgre database with 284814 records, i has looking for duplicate records, with this statmente

```
select grupo, empresa, filial, unidade, diferenciadornumero, serie, numero, count(numero) 
from conhecimento 
group by grupo, empresa, filial, unidade, diferenciadornumero, serie, numero 
having count(numero) > 1
```

And it returns to me five records:

```
1;1;9;1;2;9;24712;2
1;1;9;1;2;9;24708;2
1;1;9;1;2;9;24711;2
1;1;9;1;2;9;24713;2
1;1;9;1;2;9;24709;2
```

After that i've tryed to look this records one by one, using the composite key to bring the records, using this statmente:

```
select grupo, empresa, filial, unidade, diferenciadornumero, serie,
       numero, ctid
from conhecimento 
where grupo = 1 and empresa = 1 and
      filial = 9 and unidade = 1 and diferenciadornumero = 2 and serie = 9 and 
      numero = 24712
```

And for my surprise, this query returns just one record,

> 1;1;9;1;2;9;24712;(7986,5)

So, now i'm trying to understand how Postgre tells me that i have duplicate records in this 5 records, but when i'm trying to recover this records from the table, returns just one row,

i already used this query too

```
select *
from (SELECT grupo, empresa, filial, unidade, diferenciadornumero, serie, numero, ctid,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grupo, empresa, filial, unidade,
                                             diferenciadornumero, serie, numero
                               ) AS Row
      FROM conhecimento
     ) dups
where  dups.Row > 1
```

But without luck, someone knows whats going on?

This is the composition of my key `grupo, empresa, filial ,unidade, diferenciadornumero, serie, numero`. and my table is `conhecimento`

My best Regards

Comment: One possibility is that one or more columns are strings and there are leading or trailing spaces that you are missing.

Comment: Well, i check here, all columns are integers, is it possible have trailing spaces in integers columns?!

Comment: If all of the fields are integers, what does this part of your example output mean? `;(7986,5)`  It's either a string or two different integers?  And if it's two different integers, doesn't that mean two different rows?  Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have used this statmente to check, they are all with the right length :

`select length(grupo::VARCHAR), length(empresa::VARCHAR), length(filial::VARCHAR) ,length(unidade::VARCHAR), length(diferenciadornumero::VARCHAR), length(serie::VARCHAR), length(numero::VARCHAR), count(numero) from conhecimento  
group by grupo, empresa, filial ,unidade, diferenciadornumero, serie, numero having count(numero) > 1`

Comment: @MatBailie no, you are right, but the  `;(7986,5)` value is the `CTID` from the table, its like `ROWID` in Oracle Databases, its not part of the key

Comment: One small thing, the `row_number()` needs an `order by` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, well, did it, still 5 records, and thx for edit my question! i'm really without tips for this trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't an answer, but . . .

The code:

```
select *
from (SELECT grupo, empresa, filial, unidade, diferenciadornumero, serie, numero, ctid,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grupo, empresa, filial, unidade,
                                             diferenciadornumero, serie, numero
                               ) AS Row
      FROM conhecimento
     ) dups
where  dups.Row > 1
```

is only returning the *second* example of each record.  You don't actually want `row_number()`, you want `count()`:

```
select *
from (SELECT grupo, empresa, filial, unidade, diferenciadornumero, serie, numero, ctid,
             count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY grupo, empresa, filial, unidade,
                                         diferenciadornumero, serie, numero
                           ) AS cnt
      FROM conhecimento
     ) dups
where  dups.cnt > 1;
```